# How to read Alert message in Selenium

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver

I tried to read Alert message using `Selenium Webdriver` for following code:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
//[CDATA[
jNotify('Please select at least a dashboard',{ autoHide: true, clickOverlay: false, MinWidth: 200, TimeShown: 2000, ShowTimeEffect: 200, HideTimeEffect: 200, LongTrip: 20,HorizontalPosition: 'center', VerticalPosition: 'center', ShowOverlay: true, ColorOverlay: '#00f', OpacityOverlay: 0.3});]]>

</script>
```

But I am not able to get the error/alert message and hence unable to compare the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Get a handle to the open alert, prompt or confirmation

```
Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
```

Get the text of the alert or prompt

```
alert.getText();
```

And acknowledge the alert (equivalent to clicking "OK")

```
alert.accept();
```